# React getting undefined from object even when it exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to access the data from my object through .filter and I'm getting an object. I looked around stack overflow but all it talked about was using JSON.stringify which turns my data into a string, but I still can't access the features I need (name, age, and email). I tried using

`friend[0]` which simplified it even further but when I do `friend[0].name`, it returns name undefined.

[image: Code Image]

[image]

Here's the EditForm code, I'm eventually going to use the data for changing the input but I want to be able to access the data first since I want to use it as place holders:

```
import React from 'react';

class EditForm extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      friend: {
        name: '',
        email: '',
        age: ''
      }
    }
  }


  render(){
    const id = this.props.match.params.id;
    const friend = this.props.friends.find(friend => {return `${friend.id}` === id})
    console.log(friend)
    return(
      <div>
        <h1> Edit Friend</h1>

      </div>

    )
  }
}

export default EditForm;
```

Comment: `friend` is an array, not object

Comment: `Array.prototype.filter` returns back an array. You may want to try using `Array.prototype.find` to get back a single result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my best of knowledge this should just work. The filter function will however return an array with a single friend. Maybe this snippet will help you out. If it doesn't it might be good for you to recreate the your example in a stackblitz so that we can see it happen.

```js
const friends = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Ben',
  age: 30,
  email: 'sampleemail@email.com',
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Austen',
  age: 29,
  email: 'newemail@emails.com'
}]

const id = 2;

const friend = friends.find(friend => friend.id === id);

console.log(friend);
console.log(friend.name);
```

Comment: I tried this, it doesn’t seem to be working with my code. I tried it by itself as a snippet and it works perfectly fine. I was talking to one of my classmates and he mentioned something about using conditional rendering to show the data if the object is not null or undefined since it does start off as undefined but I really don’t know where to start with that. I would try posting my full code in here  but I’m using a local server for this project.

Comment: Would it be possible to update the question with the complete react class the function is part off?

Comment: I actually found the answer. I did use your .find method, and I just added a conditional to show that if friend exist to render something like <h1> friend.name </h1> It works. I realize that it originally is undefined so when the page loads, the data is originally undefined, which is why I'm getting an undefined error.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const friends = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Ben',
  age: 30,
  email: 'sampleemail@email.com',
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Austen',
  age: 29,
  email: 'newemail@emails.com'
}]

const id = 1;

let friend = friends.filter(friend => friend.id === id);

console.log(friend[0]);
console.log(friend[0].name);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you edit your answer and explain what that code block exactly does?